# bash how to make command work

Tags: bash

I have following bash function in my ~/.bashrc

```
function gitlab {
  MSG='first commit'
  CMD="git commit -m '${MSG}'"
  echo $CMD
  $CMD
}
```

Here is the result

```
$ gitlab 
git commit -m 'first commit'
error: pathspec 'commit'' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

What's the fix?

Answer (score 8):

BASH FAQ entry #50: ["I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely read BashFAQ/050 that Ignacio linked to.

You could try this, though:

```
function gitlab {
    local PS4='Running: '
    local msg='first commit'
    bash -xc "git commit -m '$msg'"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your commit message in double quotes, as single and double quotes mean different things to bash.

```
function gitlab {
  MSG="first commit"
  CMD=`git commit -m \"${MSG}\"`
  echo $CMD
  $CMD
}
```

Comment: The double quotes escape the single quotes, inhibiting the inhibition.

Comment: In this case (after you've edited your answer) git command will be executed on the line 3 of your script and CMD will have a command output value. So `$CMD` line will make no sense.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should use `\"` instead of `'` so it should be something like:

```
CMD="git commit -m \"${MSG}\""
```